# Vue.js - Drag n Drop / Merge

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, draggable

i'm a beginner learning Vue.js framework.
I've create a GUI using Bootstrap, and now i'm rewriting using vue.
But i'm struggling against one problem: I need to make 2 lists, where 1 of them are draggable, to drop at the other list. When i drop at the other list, i should be able to merge this draggable information into the content of the second list:

The item from list 1 must be draggable and dropped at the list 2, merging with one of the alert squares
[image]

The problem is: I'm looking for something at google, but, i can't find something that allow me drag, drop and merge. At least, not with my lack of experience.

Does anyone have any suggestion? I would really appreciate!

Sincerely,
Hugo Alves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try those libraries:

- https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable
- https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

Answer (score 1):

@elalamianas I've found a way to solve my problem using vue.draggable.

For the drag items list, i've use this code at the HTML:

```
<draggable v-model="List1" :options="{group:{name:'LIST1.name', pull:'clone'}}" @start="drag=true">
```

For the drop place, as i wanted to clone the list 1 item, and then merge at the list 2 item, i've used:

```
<draggable v-model="List2" :options="{group:{ put:'LIST1.name'}}" @add="onAdd">
```

I've use the following script:

```
 onAdd: function (evt) {
      console.log(evt)
      alert(evt.clone.id + ', ' + evt.path[1].id)
  },
  components: {
    draggable
  }
```

So, everytime i drop the item from list 1 at list 2, i receive an alert with the ID of the item dropped.

My english is not fluent, so i am sorry for the incorrect grammar. But, thanks for your suggestion!